# I need assistance with a complicated double conditional query

Tags: sql

Say I have two tables: `kids_names` And `books`

Every book has its name, the name of the kid who owns it, type of the book (lets say there are only 2 types.. a and b) and the status (read/unread).

I really need help as I have been trying unsuccessfully to get the names of the kids who own both books however with only book a is read, and book b is unread.

Comment: What Database are you using?  MySQL?  Oracle?  Postgresql?  SQL Server?  Also.. Post the code you tried, and what error you are getting.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read [ask] and [help] on how to ask a question.  Please show the table schemas, sample data, and sample expected output.

Comment: Are you saying that a specific book can only be owned by one kid? Otherwise this doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a couple of `where in` and you will be fine:

```
select name
from   kids_names
where  name in
       ( select name_of_kid
         from   books
         where  type = 'a'
         and    status = 'read'
       )
and    name in
       ( select name_of_kid
         from   books
         where  type = 'b'
         and    status = 'unread'
       )
```

Comment: @user3229164: was this helpful to you or do you need more help?

Comment: Hi Patrick.. Yes, Thank you very much!!!!! This is exactly what I was trying to do!!!!!!!! Thanks a lot again! :)))

Comment: @user3229164: No problem. Since you are new: please don't forget to mark this answer and previous answers as answered if the answers were sufficient.